# How are callbacks called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, before-save

What is the environment of a callback?

For example, in listing 6.20 of the standard Ruby on Rails Tutorial" (http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users) it has:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

Where does "email" come from? are we in a function where `email` is defined? or is actually `@email`?

Also, is there an important reason why we use `self.email` there rather than `@email` (or just `email` if it's the same as `@email`)? or is that just stylistic, or pedagogical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things going on at once here:

1. The block is called in the context of the model instance being saved so `self` in the block is the `User` being saved. The block is also passed an argument but you don't have to use it.
2. Local variables in Ruby aren't explicitly declared, they are implicitly declared when you first try to give them a value.
3. The implicit receiver for method calls is `self`.
4. But local variables take precedence over method calls so a mutator method (such as `self.email=`) needs an explicit receiver to distinguish it from a local variable.
5. Instance variables (`@email`) don't have anything to do with *attributes* in ActiveRecord models.
6. The accessor (`self.email` or just `email` if there is no `email` local variable) and mutator methods (`self.email=`) for ActiveRecord objects work with attributes, not instance variables.

So this:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase } # (1)
```

could also be written as:

```
before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase } # (2)
```

or even:

```
before_save { |user| user.send(:email=, user.send(:email).downcase) } # (3)
```

The main functional difference is that **(2)** requires the `email` and `email=` methods to be public.

Comment: Would it also be the same as self.email=self.email.downcase?

Comment: or email = email.downcase?

Comment: Yes to `self.email = self.email.downcase`, no to `email = email.downcase` as that would be using a local variable called `email` (see **(4)**). Mutator methods always have to be called with an explicit receiver to distinguish them from local variable assignments.

Comment: Ok, in that case, where do the getters and setters get created? They're not in the file, and nothing seems to be saying "create getters and setters for the following variables" or anything...

Comment: @BrianPostow ActiveRecord knows which attributes there are based on the DB (or via the schema cache), [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) is probably also involved.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks run in the object's (User's in your example) scope. `self.email=` is an object method, while `@email` is an instance variable.

ActiveRecord automatically creates methods (getters and setters) for all columns in a corresponding database table (I assume that you have `email` column in `users` table).

Notice, that using `@email =` instead of `self.email =` will create instance variable and will not update a column in a database.